# Optimize the recursion depth

Tags: python, java

How to optimize this code: Have to find all possible combinations (range [1,K]) of digits in a given string of digits, with the condition that digits are in same order.
Eg: If the given string is "123" and K is 200, there are four possible arrays: [1, 2, 3], [12, 3], [1, 23], [123].

```
def findComb(stri):
    if len(stri) <= 1 :
        return [stri]
    arr=findComb(stri[1:len(stri)])
    destArr=[]
    for i in arr:
        destArr.append(stri[0]+i)
        destArr.append(stri[0]+','+i)
    return destArr


n, K=map(str,input().split())
K=int(K)
s=input()
l=findComb(s)
print(l)

lis=[]
for i in l:
    f=0
    if ',' in i:
        li=i.split(',')
        for j in li:
            if int(j)>K:
                f=1
                break
        if f==0:
            lis.append(li)
    else:
        if int(i)<=K:
            lis.append(i)

print(len(lis)%(10^9+7))
```

My try is given above.

Any suggestions on how to optimize it?

Comment: what is the meaning of that "range", or `K`? Why the [tag:java] tag - posted code is NOT Java?

Comment: What do you want to optimize for? Speed? Memory usage? Did you already use a profiler? This question may fit better on [codereview.se]. See [ask] for questions that fit stackoverflow.